# Ladder method for lcm and gcd

Tags: gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

I think the easiest method for finding lcm and gcd is the [ladder method](http://pgdemath2011.blogspot.in/2011/08/caution-beware-of-how-you-use-ladder.html), which can even be extended to more than two integers. For example,

[image]
$$
\text{lcm}(48,72,108)=2*2*3*3*2*2*1*3=432\\\text{gcd}(48,72,108)=2*2*3=12
$$
Till $3^\text{rd}$ step there are prime factors for all three numbers. But, from step $4$ only two have common prime factors. Thus while finding gcd we only take prime factors till $3^\text{rd}$ step.

What really is happening in this method, particularly when we ignore $9$ in $4^\text{th}$ step and $3$ in $5^\text{th}$ step while dividing by common factors?. What property is used in this method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is going on at the top is finding factors common to all the numbers.  The black $2,2,3$ are those.  The product of them is the greatest common divisor of all the numbers.  Once we get to $4,6,9$ there are no longer any common factors, so the greatest common divisor has been determined.  Now we are using the fact that the least common multiple of $an, bn$ is $n\operatorname{lcm}(\frac an, \frac bn)$.  We use that until there are no pairs of numbers with a common factor, here $2,1,3$.  Finally we use the fact that $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)=ab$ whenever $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Comment: Thanx. So you mean lcm$(an,bn)=n.lcm(a,b)$. Ex: lcm$(6,9)=3.$lcm$(2,3)=3.6=18$. But what about three numbers?. lcm$(4,6,9)$=lcm$(4,$lcm$(6,9))$=lcm$(4,3.$lcm$(2,3))=?$. Now what property 'd i use?

Comment: As long as $a$ is coprime to $bc$ you also have $\operatorname{lcm}(a,bc)=b\operatorname{lcm}(ac)$, so in your last example $\operatorname{lcm}(4,3\cdot \operatorname{lcm}(2,3))=3\cdot \operatorname{lcm}(4,\operatorname{lcm}(2,3))$